# gradle archive file generated with wrong name

Tags: gradle

```
jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'dummy'
    archiveVersion = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bootJar
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven mavenRepoConfig
    }
}

publish.dependsOn bootJar
```

I am having an issue with gradle build, the archive is not been published to maven local with the right name, as the config above says it should be generated with the baseName = dummy but instead the name of the project is being used to generate the boot jar, does anyone have faces this same issue before? thanks!

Comment: `bootJar` is different task from `jar` ; if you are using spring see boot - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.4/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives